# How to get ComboViewer from a Widget

Tags: java, swt

How can I get a reference to the ComboViewer from the widget. For example - to get a Combo, we don something like this:

```
Combo[] comboControls = WidgetHierarchy.getDescendantsByType((Composite) page.getControl(), Combo.class);
```

ComboViewer is not a control so can't apply this. Any way to achieve this?

Comment: You can get the `Combo` from the `ComboViewer` by calling `ComboViewer#getCombo()`. `Combo` is a `Widget`.

Comment: @baz: But how do I get the ComboViewer is my question

Comment: From the `Combo`? You can't. Unless you store that information yourself.

Comment: No from the widget. I am testing a UI and for which I need to change the selection. To do that I need the ComboViewer

Comment: You can't get it out of thin air, you need to have a reference. What "widget" are you talking about?

Comment: I have a dialog which has a ComboViewer built with a Combo. How do I get the ComboViewer is what is bugging me

Comment: You'll have to post more of your code. I'm afraid we're terribly bad at reading minds.

Comment: ComboViewer is not a Control or Widget so you can't find it by searching the descendants of a Composite.